# Waitpid Usage and Bash Scripting

Tags: bash, unix, scripting, pid

I'm trying to write a program in which a program continuously takes in a user input through a while loop, and in each loop forks a new child of the current program process while running a shell script. This is what I currently have:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    while(!feof(stdin)){
        printf("Port Number:");
        fgets(portno, 100, stdin);
        input[strlen(portno) - 1] = '\0';
        pid_t pid = fork();

        if (pid < 0){
            die("fork did not work");
        } else if (pid == 0){
            fprintf(stderr, "[pid=%d] ", (int)getpid());
            fprintf(stderr, "process started on port %s\n", portno);
           execl("./netcattest.sh", "netcattest.sh", portno, (char *)0);
            die("program failed");
        } else {
            /*
            if (waitpid(.... NEED HELP ON THIS PART
            */
            fprintf(stderr, "[pid=%d] ", (int)pid);
            fprintf(stderr, "program terminated\n");
        }
    }

return 0;
}
```

My problem is reading the waitpid documentation, I'm slightly unclear as to how to use the function. What I want to happen is when the program is a parent process, I want to be able to somehow identify all processes that have been currently terminated.

For example, if I ran the loop 3 times, and somewhere after the second loop the first process terminates, i want to somehow be able to identify the pid of the process that terminated.

I know it involves using the WNOHANG option, but I'm really confused as to how it works.

Thank you guys very much.

EDIT: Also, is there a quick way to do the 4 indents for a piece of code rather than just spacing every line individually?

Comment: Yes, select the code and click the `{}` icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used this functionality, but my understanding of the documentation is that you should do the following:

```
int status;
pid_t pid = waitpid(-1, &status, WNOHANG);
```

at this point, `pid` will be -1 for error, 0 if no process has exited, or otherwise the PID of a process which has exited (chosen arbitrarily; to wait for all the processes, just keep calling it). You can examine `status` with the various macro functions specified on the man page to determine how the process ended and what its exit code was.

Comment: Is there any way to get it so that I can pull all the processes that have exited versus only arbitrarily picking one? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I edited my answer -- just keep calling waitpid until it returns 0. Since waitpid only returns a single PID and status, if it harvested multiple processes, information would be lost.